# Selenium is unable to locate the element for the search bar in Pinterest

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a webscraper that downloads images from Pinterest's search results.

I'm in the process of making the script click on the search bar. However, the program does not recognize the search bar element.

Here's the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python Projects\Nova pasta\geckodriver.exe'))

browser.get("https://pinterest.com/") # Opens Firefox and enters Pinterest

login = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.erh") # Looks for the login button
login.click() # Clicks on it

email = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email") # Looks for the email box
email.send_keys("lol no") # Types in the email

password = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#password")
password.send_keys("lol neither")

login2 = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".red > div:nth-child(1)")
login2.click()

search = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/input")
search.click()
search.send_keys("South Korea")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I've already tried using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong locator for the search input element.
You should also use Expected Conditions explicit waits.
This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python Projects\Nova pasta\geckodriver.exe'))
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

browser.get("https://pinterest.com/") # Opens Firefox and enters Pinterest

login = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.erh") # Looks for the login button
login.click() # Clicks on it

email = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email") # Looks for the email box
email.send_keys("lol no") # Types in the email

password = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#password")
password.send_keys("lol neither")

login2 = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".red > div:nth-child(1)")
login2.click()

search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='searchBoxInput']")))
search.click()
search.send_keys("South Korea")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You should use the `wait` object on the previous steps as well...